# How can i check if android device supports a library?

Tags: java, android, classloader

I created an Android application with IR blaster and I want my code to check if an Android device supports these libraries. When another device installs my app, it crashes. How can I avoid this?

I want my code to get info about whether the phone supports my app.

Comment: Since that API is not publicly documented AFAICT, it will be difficult for anyone other than HTC to help you. Do you use a `<uses-library>` element in the manifest to indicate that you want to use this library?

Comment: Nothing inside manifest....only inside java

Comment: Another possible approach is to check if the device has com.sec.feature.spen_usp feature, but as far I know it works starting from JB....how works this?

Comment: I doubt that a Samsung item (`com.sec.feature.spen_usp`) is related to an HTC feature. Regardless, you will need to contact HTC AFAIK. I adjusted the tags in hope that HTC will pick up your SO question. However, since you had to contact them separately to gain access to this partner API in the first place, presumably they told you there how to get support for that partner API.

Comment: Ok.I will send email to HTC.Thanks.

Comment: Hello. I'm trying to do a school project for my HTC One using the IR blaster. Do you have any sample code, or any other tutorial, on how to send an IR command? I'm only interested in sending an IR command, without "learning" it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a similar problem to loading JDBC drivers.  If the drivers don't exist you don't want to crash out your entire app.

The basic principle of the solution is to use [Class.forName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)

This lets you check if the class exists and throws an exception if it doesn't.

**Edit:**

To be clear - the reason why this works and why this is *necessary* is that if Java is unable to execute code because it doesn't have a class then Java will treat this as a catastrophic failure (an [Error](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Error.html) - specificity a [NoClassDefFoundError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html)).  Therefore executing any direct reference to a missing class will throw this Error.  According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Error.html):

> When errors are thrown, they should not be caught by application code.

However when `Class.forName()` is unable to find a class (or more direct calls to a [ClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)) an [Exception](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) is thrown.  Because this is an exception and not an Error it can be caught.  And because the function takes a String as an argument, you don't need to directly reference the class (just give it's name in the string) so the check can be performed without directly referencing the class and thus without crashing out your program.

Comment: did it work? could using a try catch on an initialization function also work instead ?

Comment: no, i didn't mean it , as this is what the post says. i asked if what the post says works, and if as an alternative, trying to add a try-catch for the initialization function would work too (again, instead of using the Class.ForName()) .

Comment: No. you get an Error not an Exception. As per the documentation you really should not catch errors, you get into very dangerous territory when you do that.