# How to check programmatically if a library exist in apk

Tags: android

I am new to android app development. and creating a native app. I create two libraries, one with symbols exported (for test purpose) and one without any (to be used in product apk). Corresponding linking to these i generate 1 test apk and product apk. Only difference being the library being loaded.

Now in my apk i call load library and i want to provide the string name of the library, which should be different for both apk's. 
So wanted to check if there is a way to pull the library which exist in my apk and call a load for it. Any solutions / suggestions around this would be helpful?

Comment: Try using Class.forName and catching the ClassNotFoundException. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002421/how-can-i-check-if-android-device-supports-a-library